# How to turn irobot create by exact angle using brown package?

Tags: ros, create, irobot-create-2-1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get an iRobot Create to turn by 90 degrees. I am using the irobot_create_2_1 driver. I am trying to subscribe to \odom topic to read the orientation but am not sure exactly which parameter gives the current angle. I know Create provides an opcode for wait_angle (opcode 157). Can I use this for turning using the brown driver?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60142/how-to-turn-irobot-create-by-exact-angle-using-brown-package?/) by [shwgupte](https://answers.ros.org/users/4626/shwgupte/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nouman Tahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/20072/nouman-tahir/) on 2014-11-05**:
tryin to connect irobot using bam bluetooth module, but it returns "bad data" and "OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable" on driver.py....plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One way to do this, is to determine the heading between odom and base_link which is published by the driver. An example of this can be found here in albany-ros-pkg [seminar2011/square_with_tf.py](https://code.google.com/p/albany-ros-pkg/source/browse/branches/seminar2011/ex_move/bin/square_with_tf.py). This was an example piece of code we used to draw squares on the ground with that same driver, although it was last run 2 years ago so something might have changed in the driver or ROS since then.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shwgupte](https://answers.ros.org/users/4626/shwgupte/) on 2013-04-07**:
Thanks so much for your reply. I tried using that code. However it does not make a perfect square, it overshoots the angle by quite a large amount. Are there any values I would need to tweak in the code?

**Comment by [shwgupte](https://answers.ros.org/users/4626/shwgupte/) on 2013-04-07**:
It may be something very obvious but since I have never used python before, I am finding it difficult to understand. Thanks

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-04-07**:
The turning odometry on the create is pretty bad... honestly, +/- 20 degrees on a 90 degree angle is probably the best you can expect.